# Expresion lambda: anidada , explota no se que hace pero no funciona como deberia

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, poo, dapper

tengo un problema con una expresión lambda básicamente yo tengo un crud de Dapper que en el metodo get recibe una expresion lambda y esta la envio a otro metodo que crea la sentencia que necesita where (sql), y cuando la obtiene la añade a la sentencia inicial y la ejecuta, funcionaba todo bien hasta que no se porque motivo hay una de las peticiones que se envia de forma incorrecta, como que se envia toda la anidacion y cuando este metodo va construir where lo interpreta como que es nullo y procede a fallecer

```
private string GetFilterExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
  {
      var binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)filter.Body;
      var left = binaryExpression.Left as MemberExpression;
      var right = binaryExpression.Right as ConstantExpression;
      


      if (left != null && right != null)
      {
          var fieldName = left.Member.Name;
          var value = right.Value;
  
          // Devuelve la cláusula WHERE con el filtro.
          return $"{fieldName} = {value}";
      }

      throw new ArgumentException("Expresión de filtro no válida.");
  }
```

Aca dejo el metodo get

```
public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
   {
       string tableName= typeof(T).Name;
       if (GetFilterExpression(filter) != null)
       {
           string sql = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE {GetFilterExpression(filter)}";
           
           String expr= GetFilterExpression(filter);
           System.Console.WriteLine("Datos de la consulta");
           System.Console.WriteLine(expr);
           System.Console.WriteLine(sql);
           var result= _connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<T>(sql);
           return result;
       }
       else
       {
           string sql = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}";
           return _connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<T>(sql);
       }
     
   }
```

y aca es donde empieza a fallar

```
public virtual List<Usuario> GetAll(Expression<Func<Usuario, bool>>? filter = null)
{
   List<Usuario> users = base.GetAll(filter);
   int cedulon;

   foreach (var user in users)
   {
   
     
       
       if (_administradorDal.Get((e) => e.Cedula == cedulon) != null){
           user.Rol = "Administrador";
       }
       else if (_docenteDal.Get((e) => e.Cedula == user.Cedula) != null)
       {
           user.Rol = "Docente";
       }
       else if (_estudianteDal.Get((e) => e.Cedula == user.Cedula) != null)
       {
           user.Rol = "Estudiante";
       }
       else if (_operadorDal.Get((e) => e.Cedula == user.Cedula) != null)
       {
           user.Rol = "Operador";
       }
   }

   return users;
}
```

la expresion que llega a GetFilterExpressions es:

```
{e => (e.Cedula == value(DpUserDal+<>c__DisplayClass7_0).user.Cedula)}
```

Ya probe no enviar el user.cedula, tipo guardarlo en un int previamente

Comment: ¿Cómo podemos reproducir el tema? ¿Qué ejemplos consideras para verificar? Lecturas sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos :D

Comment: Francamente estas complejizando tu problema al extremo e innecesariamente, y el problema de hacer esto, es que cuando aparece un error es difícil solucionarlo. Tu función `GetFilterExpression` solo funciona para un solo caso (cuando es `=`), no funciona para los distintos, ni para expresiones anidadas (`and` y `or`) ni menos con paréntesis.  Un árbol de expresiones se recorre justamente como árbol para ir armando la sentencia, si tu no necesitas eso mejor pasar 2 argumentos "normales" en la función y ya. Ahora quizás este es solo un código de ejemplo y tu tienes lo que te digo en el original

Comment: Luego tu función `Get` cuando no hay filtro retorna el primer elemento al azar, tampoco le veo sentido. Semánticamente el `Get` debería retornar uno, pero para eso hay que pasar su Id siempre, no le veo sentido a retornar cualquiera de la tabla

Comment: @Yussef Como lo puedo descomplejizar? no le puedo pasar directamente dos argumentos pq necesito que sea reutilizable para todos, capas con alguna notacion de la variable o algo y que interprete cual es un primary key

Comment: @lo de retornar un default es que me quedo de la implementacion no me di cuenta realmente

Comment: @DeRep67 Pero si lo que tienes ahora es lo menos versátil del mundo y básicamente lo que estas haciendo es pasar 2 argumentos solo que contenido en una clase Expression https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbPFd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como te decía en los comentarios, elegiste un camino sumamente complejo para resolver este problema. Mi concejo es que no uses `Expression`.

Pero para responder tu pregunta, tienes un problema en tu función `GetFilterExpression`, esta función solo funciona para un caso y es cuando tienes es forma:

```
GetFilterExpression(x => x.PropInt == 1);
```

- A la izquierda una propiedad a la cual quieres rescatar el nombre
- La operación es un igual lógico
- A la derecha una constante

Cualquier otro caso no funciona

No funciona para cualquier otra comparación que igualmente retorna un booleano, porque tu siempre conviertes a `=`

```
GetFilterExpression(x => x.PropInt != 1); // retorna: PropInt = 1
GetFilterExpression(x => x.PropInt > 1);  // retorna: PropInt = 1
GetFilterExpression(x => x.PropInt < 1);  // retorna: PropInt = 1
```

---

No funciona con algo que no sea un número

```
GetFilterExpression(x => x.PropString = "unstring"); // retorna: PropInt = unstring
// Deberia retornar: PropInt = 'unstring' con comillas
```

---

No funciona con null

```
GetFilterExpression(x => x.PropString = null); // retorna: PropInt = 
// Deberia retornar: PropInt is null
```

---

No funciona con una expresión compuesta

```
GetFilterExpression(x => x.PropString = null && x.PropInt = 1) ; // Se cae el programa
```

---

Y así puedo seguir señalando casos todo el día, porque básicamente lo que se requiere es traducir un lenguaje C# a SQL que es bastante trabajo

**Pero el problema puntual de tu código es que tampoco funciona para variables (solo funciona para constantes)**

Es decir esto no funciona:

```
_administradorDal.Get((e) => e.Cedula == cedulon)
_docenteDal.Get((e) => e.Cedula == user.Cedula) 
_estudianteDal.Get((e) => e.Cedula == user.Cedula) 
_operadorDal.Get((e) => e.Cedula == user.Cedula)
```

Porque lo de la derecha sería `MemberExpression` no un `ConstantExpression` como tu lo tienes y para obtener el valor debes compilarlo, es decir debería ser algo así:

```
private string GetFilterExpression(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    var binaryExpression = (BinaryExpression)filter.Body;
    var left = binaryExpression.Left as MemberExpression;
    var right = binaryExpression.Right as MemberExpression;

    if (left != null && right != null)
    {
        var valor = Expression.Lambda(right).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        var fieldName = left.Member.Name;
        var value = valor;
  
        return $"{fieldName} = {value}";
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Expresión de filtro no válida.");
}
```

---

Acá te dejo un ejemplo que soluciona varios de los problemas, pero tienes que terminarlo

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int a = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(GetFilterExpression<A>(x => x.PropInt == a));
        Console.WriteLine(GetFilterExpression<A>(x => x.PropInt == 2));
        Console.WriteLine(GetFilterExpression<A>(x => a != x.PropInt));
        Console.WriteLine(GetFilterExpression<A>(x => (x.PropInt == 2 || x.PropString=="algo") && x.OtraProp==false));
        Console.WriteLine(GetFilterExpression<A>(x => !x.OtraProp));
        Console.WriteLine(GetFilterExpression<A>(x => x.PropString == null));

    }

    private static string GetFilterExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    => GetFilterExpression(filter.Body)
        .Replace("= null", "is null") //reemplazamos para estos casos especiales
        .Replace("<> null", "is not null");

    //recorre el árbol recursivamente
    private static string GetFilterExpression(Expression exp)
    {
        if (exp is BinaryExpression bexp) return GetFilterExpression(bexp);
        if (exp is UnaryExpression uexp) return GetFilterExpression(uexp);
        if (exp is MemberExpression mexp)
        {
            if(mexp?.Expression?.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter) return mexp.Member.Name; //retorna el nombre de la propiedad
            
            //retorna el valor de una variable 
            var valor = Expression.Lambda(mexp).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
            return GetConstant(valor);
        }
       
        return GetFilterMember(exp);

    }

    //Resuelve para los BinaryExpression 
    private static string GetFilterExpression(BinaryExpression exp)
    {
        var left = GetFilterExpression(exp.Left);
        var right = GetFilterExpression(exp.Right);
        var op = GetFilterMember(exp);
        return $"({left} {op} {right})"; ;
    }

    //Resuelve para los UnaryExpression
    private static string GetFilterExpression(UnaryExpression exp)
    {
        var right = GetFilterExpression(exp.Operand);
        var op = GetFilterMember(exp);
        return $"({op} {right})"; ;
    }

    //Resuelve para los otros casos, principalmente las operaciones
    private static string GetFilterMember(Expression ex)
    => ex.NodeType switch
    {
        ExpressionType.AndAlso => "and",
        ExpressionType.OrElse => "or",
        ExpressionType.Equal => "=",
        ExpressionType.NotEqual => "<>",
        ExpressionType.Not => "Not",
        //HAY QUE SEGUIR AGREGANDO ExpressionType a la lista, para casos de mayor, menor, mayor o igual, etc
        ExpressionType.Constant => GetConstant(((ConstantExpression)ex).Value),
        _ => "" ,
    };

   //Coloca las comillas cuando es necesario y pone null si es el caso
    private static string GetConstant(object? Value)
    {
          
        if(Value is null) return "null";
        if(Value is string or DateTime)  return $"'{Value}'";
        return Value.ToString();
    }

}

//clase de pruebas
public class A
{
    public string PropString { get; set; }
    public int PropInt { get; set; }
    public bool OtraProp { get; set; }
}
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]